# Can't see the contents of vector or other containers (e.g map) while debugging (C++ program) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, visual-studio-debugging

I have written a simple `C++(11)` program to test the debugger in Visual studio code in Windows. I am using MinGW distributions for compiler options. 
I have setup my `tasks.json` and `launch.json` as per the doc here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Here is the sample cpp code:

```
typedef std::vector<int> vi;    
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    fast();
    int tests = 1;
    cin >> tests;
    while(tests--)
    {
        int n = 5, k = 25;
        cin >> n >> k;
        vi permutation(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> permutation[i];
        }

        // vi permutation = {5,4,3,2,1};
        auto ans = solve(permutation, k);
       // other logic goes here

    }
    return 0;
}
```

My `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-std=c++11",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "echo": false,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "shared",
                "clear": false,
                "showReuseMessage": false
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

My `launch.json` file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am seeing this in the debugger window:
[image]

As per the doc, I should see a screen something like this:
[image]

Am I setting something wrong here? Why am I not seeing the content of containers? I have observed that I can't see the values of other containers also.

Comment: I have installed MinGW distro from here: https://nuwen.net/

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but for linux environment, any links for the same, the exisiting answers on other posts are not resolving the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue when I installed the MINGW from the site which you have mentioned. Then I installed MINGW from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download) mentioned in the [wiki](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and it started working fine. Please have a try once.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/69
{
"description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
"text": "python import sys;sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gcc-8/python');from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers;register_libstdcxx_printers(None)",
"ignoreFailures": false
},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).